What is fundamental object we are looking for in QFT?
I have some questions in studying quantum field theory.
In Classical mechanics, we construct the Lagrangian $L = T-V$ and by taking the Euler-Lagrange equation we get equation of motion. And by solving that equation, we obtain 'trajectory of a particle depending on time.'
In quantum mechanics, we construct a Hamiltonian and obtain Schrödinger equation and by solving the equation we obtain a 'wave function ( an element ( vector ) in the corresponding Hilbert space ).'
And my question is, in Quantum field theory, canonical second quantization, what is fundamental object we are looking for? Perhaps, an element (vector) in the corresponding 'Fock' space? If so, is there any
relevant  (possibly partial)  differential equations to obtain such object? What?
P.s. A little, I want to understand the QFT in perspective of theory of partial differential equations.
I followed the calculation process of Canonical quantization in several standard QFT books, but I can't grasp what's going on at all until now. Can anyone teach about this question more clearly and friendly?
EDIT : I think this question is a rather fundamental question about basis of QFT's system - possibly relevant to rigorous mathematical construction of quantum field theory - and can be briefly explained to the point, but I don't know why it is voted closed. Can anyone vote to reopen?

"I followed the calculation process of Canonical quantization in several standard QFT books, but I can't grasp what's going on at all until now. Can anyone explain about these stuff more clearly and friendly?" You seem to be asking for us to write an entire textbook for you... This is not the right place for such a broad question.

That being said, for QFT you are interested in the same things you are interested in with Quantum Mechanics. QFT is just a reformulation of quantum mechanics in a way that allows us to deal with changing particle number and has other nice properties.

In QFT, one is often less concerned with an explicit representation of the state since often one is concerned with scattering amplitudes that are "just" vacuum expectation values. And often the only interesting property of the vacuum state is that it is annihilated by the destruction operators.

I would recommend reading a relatively easy qft book like "Quantum field theory for the gifted amateur" by Lancaster and Blundell.

Quantum field theory is a formalism ideally suited to study fundamental dynamics. So what it calculates is a probability (amplitude) for certain events to take place. These events are often quantified as scattering cross-sections. So, to answer the OP question: the "fundamental object" in QFT is a scattering cross-section. That is indeed what is being measured in high-energy particle-physics experiments.
The analyses in QFT do not generally manifest as the solutions of partial differential equations. Instead they are the results of integrals. The role of partial differential equations are usually to describe the evolution of a system while experiencing some dynamics. In particle physics, the focus is on scattering produced by such dynamics.
One may perhaps consider a system such as a specific quantum state that evolves due to fundamental dynamics. The scattering process would then have to be modeled as a continuous process experienced by that state. Such an investigation would require a partial differential equation describing the evolution. It may not be a trivial exercise to formulate such a description. Moreover, I am not sure there is any context that can justify such an investigation.

Thank you. I am rereading the beggining of Schwartz's quantum field theory book. I am still confusing. I think it would be helpful to see an example of applying QFT to solving a specific physical problem or calculation. Perhaps, are there any examples you can recommend?  Anyway your overall answer will be helpful.

Most QFT textbooks show the explicit calculations of basic processes in QED, such as bremsstrahlung, Compton scattering, and pair creation. Peskin and Schroeder gives a good account.

O.K. Thank you :)

@Plantation This is the physical problem you should study: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomalous_magnetic_dipole_moment

@Avantgarde : O.K. I will refer. Thanks.
